# SQL INSERT ... SELECT continues to insert indefinately

Tags: mysql

I've been putzing around with sql, trying to get a better grasp on my usage of it, it was going well until i got to this line of code:

```
    INSERT INTO 
citizens(lName,fName,gender,weight,psychosis,skank,status,is_pregnant,conceptionDate) 
SELECT l.lastname, f.name, f.gender, '1','1','1','1','1','1' FROM firstNames f, lastName l
LIMIT 1
```

I'm not sure what I did, but the code continue ad infinium. i wanted it to insert only a couple of records, but it's inserted well over 5Million records as of right now.

because people are asking for it here is the datatype for each column:

> cid int(11)
>
> fName text
>
> lName text
>
> gender enum('male','female')
>
> weight, psychosis, skank, status and ConceptionDate all INT
>
> is_pregnant enum('yes','no')

some of these are getting update/renamed (name status is now rStatus and is_pregnant has a third option for 'in_labor') but that shouldn't effect anything else.

Comment: I've never seen limit being used in combination with a select for an insert. That aside how many entries are in firstnames and lastnames respectively? as with that select you combine all possible combinations of both....and if we take even 1000 entries..........it will end up being QUITE a LOT entries there (1000000 if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I think the limit was there from the phpmyadmin console. That being said, there are far fewer combos than there are being inserted (also, as far as i can tell, there appears to be no data actually being inserted, It says ~2,899,478,123 entries but when I click on the database view, there's nothing in it)

Comment: according to the table def you have a few possible probs.  the int blockls should be put as 1 not '1'. additionally I'm not sure if the is_pregnant enum likes it if you put in '1' as value. Is cid an auto increment (I take it that its the primary key)?

Comment: please post or mark answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a cross join there will be n * m entries will be there ( Where n  no of rows in lname and m being no. of rows in fname).

So it will be wise to use `'INNER JOIN'`(if both firstname and lastname are mandatory) or `'LEFTJOIN'`(If lastname is not mandatory).

`INSERT INTO 
citizens(lName,fName,gender,weight,psychosis,skank,status,is_pregnant,conceptionDate) values 
(SELECT l.lastname, f.name, f.gender, '1','1','1','1','1','1' FROM firstNames f INNER JOIN  lastName l ON f.id=l.id LIMIT 1)`.

Hope this will work.

Comment: inner join, cross join depends on what he wants to achieve (in this case he made a cross join which for test data could have its right for existence so the inner join isn't necessarily necessary there)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to JOIN your tables.

```
SELECT l.lastname, f.name, f.gender, '1','1','1','1','1','1' 
FROM firstNames f INNER JOIN lastName l on f.someID = l.someID
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: he is joining his tables. He is doing a cross join

Answer (score 0):

if "conceptionDate" column is varchar / date type column.
If you insert '1' in "conceptionDate" as date column than it will give you an error.

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7ebfa/3)

Comment: conception date is just an INT. this is for a game with a custom time scale so i needed to essentially reinvent the clock.

Comment: @PatrickPierson can you put up what data type each column is? (into your question)